# Convert Json keys into lower case

Tags: c#, json.net

i have a json in string like this

```
{
  "P1" : "value1",
  "P2" : "value2"
}
```

i want to convert keys into lower case like this

```
{
  "p1" : "value1",
  "p2" : "value2"
}
```

any idea how to do this ? i have try to iterate through json properties like this

```
JObject.Parse(jsonStr).Properties()
```

and try to rename it but the IProperty.Name is readonly.

Comment: Have you looked into the `JsonProperty` attribute or `JsonPropertyName` attribute (depending on if you are using Newtonsoft or System.Text.Json)?

Comment: i am using newtonsoft let me check

Comment: You can create a new class-model with a named properties and make the parse. 
https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the names by using `Replace` method.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var prop in obj.Properties().ToList())
{
    prop.Replace(new JProperty(prop.Name.ToLower(), prop.Value));
}
```

Note that this only does it for the immediate properties and does not recurse through all subproperties. This should give you an idea on how to update the property names (to lower case)